# how to auto detect the current form element with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam appending a form from desktop view and adding it to mobile view (including scripts) using  `append()` . Since Iam appending same class name and ID for form elements., on submitting form., it is identifying the mobile layout form and passing empty value on trying to get value using `document.getElementsByClassName('txtbox').value`.

As per my requirement., I need to give index to identify each form while appending. like `document.getElementsByClassName('txtbox')[0].value`. I have done an approach for same. But not getting how to increment index value on appneding. I have created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/k519dZwxciKJDV0SWBoH?p=preview) for same. Please let me know what I have missed.

Here is the sample code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $(".div1").html();
    $(".div2").append(data);
    $("form").submit(function(){
      
      console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('txtbox').value);
      /*console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('txtbox')[0].value);
      console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('txtbox')[1].value) ; */
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="div1">
      // data to be copied
      <form class="search-container" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();window.open(abc/cde/+'?q='+document.getElementsByClassName('txtbox').value),'_self');">
         <input type="text" class="txtbox" id="txtbox" placeholder="enter here...">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" /></form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="div2">
      //data to be appended
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have passed form object inside function call and used that param to identify current form.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $(".div1").html();
    $(".div2").append(data);
});

function submitForm(form){
  var txtValue = $(form).find('.txtbox').val();
  console.log(txtValue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="div1">
      // data to be copied
      <form class="search-container" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();submitForm(this);">
         <input type="text" class="txtbox" id="txtbox" placeholder="enter here...">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" /></form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="div2">
      //data to be appended
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `$(this).find()` to select `.txtbox` inside the form.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('.txtbox').val());
    return false; // for debugging
});
```

Also, please note that `id` should be unique in the documnt.

Comment: I have made few changes to your answer and got it working. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through you class list like so:

```
    var txtboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("txtbox");
    for(var i = 0; i < txtboxes.length; i++){
        // ... process each element here
        $(txtboxes[i]).append(data);
    }
```