# AJAX Only Gets Values For Last Form Only

Tags: php, sql, ajax, forms, input

I am using AJAX to automatically update text inputs and textareas and save them to the database.

Everything works until there are two of form the same form. I figured out the AJAX function is taking the values from the form. I checked with `console.log(data)`. I wonder if the last form is overriding everything.

It also works perfectly fine if all names are unique. However, my SQL code will have so much repetition and it won't be efficient if the user makes 10 of these forms.

How can I make it so this doesn't happen?

Thank you!

`index.php`

```
<form method="post" class="form-input">
    <input type="hidden" name="position" value="1" class="position">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="th">Offer Heading</td>
                <td><input name="heading" class="text-input" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="th">Description</td>
                <td><textarea name="description"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="th">Call-To-Action</td>
                <td><input name="call_to_action" class="text-input" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

`script.js`

```
    var timeoutId;
    $('textarea, .text-input').on('input propertychange change', function() {
        console.log('Textarea Change');

        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change
            saveToDB();
        }, 1000);
    });
    
    function saveToDB() {
        console.log('Saving to the db');
        var data = $(".form-input").serialize();
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                console.log('completed');
            }
        });
    }
    
    $('.form-input').submit(function(e) {
        saveToDB();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: "*until there are two of form the same form*" - should this read "*until there are 2 forms on the same page*"?  If yes, it suggests that both forms are updating the same single record in the DB?  How do you identify which record is being updated?  Usually there might be a hidden input with a `record_id` or something like that but there isn't one here - or is that what `position` is?  Why not just have a single form on the page?  If not, we probably need to see your PHP/SQL - it sounds like the SQL is updating all fields in the record, rather than just those that are included in the POST.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to auto detect the current form element with same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068478/how-to-auto-detect-the-current-form-element-with-same-class-name)

Comment: how do you thing js should know which form to use? you have to use a select form based on the submit button. like $(this).parent(".form-input")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet that demonstrates some of the points made in the comments to the question. One further change I made is that I am no longer using the global variable `timeoutId` to store the timeout handle. Instead I store this information in a `.timeoutId`-property of the current form. This will prevent the error of not storing the data from one form if a text field in another form is changed directly afterwards.

```js
$('textarea, .text-input').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    const frm=$(this).closest("form")[0];
    console.log(frm.name,'Textarea Change');

    clearTimeout(frm.timeoutId);
    frm.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 3 seconds (3000 ms) after the last change
        saveToDB(frm);
    }, 3000);
});

function saveToDB(frm) {
    console.log(frm.name,'Saving to the db');
    var data = $(frm).serialize();
    console.log(data);
    /* $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('completed');
        }
    });*/
}

$('.form-input').submit(function(e) {
    saveToDB(this);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="form-input" name="one">
<input type="hidden" name="position" value="1" class="position">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="th">Offer Heading</td>
            <td><input name="heading" class="text-input" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="th">Description</td>
            <td><textarea name="description"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="th">Call-To-Action</td>
            <td><input name="call_to_action" class="text-input" type="text"> <button>go</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form><hr>
<form method="post" class="form-input" name="two">
<input type="hidden" name="position" value="2" class="position">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="th">Offer Heading</td>
            <td><input name="heading" class="text-input" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="th">Description</td>
            <td><textarea name="description"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="th">Call-To-Action</td>
            <td><input name="call_to_action" class="text-input" type="text"> <button>go</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```